# What is the difference between using rails form_tag and html form code in an erb file?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had a problem with a rails app I am making. It is an e-commerce site, and on the page where the  user enters their billing info, posting the form causing the cart information to be lost.

I solved the problem by changing the markup in the erb file. The first code for the form was:

```
<form method="post" id="checkout" action="<%= url_for :action => :place_order %>" >
    <%= submit_tag "Place Order" %>
</form>
```

This didn't work, so I tried the following:

```
<% form_tag :method => 'post', :controller => 'checkout', :action => 'place_order' do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Place Order 2' %>
<% end %>
```

Does anyone know why the second piece of code does not cause the cart information to be discarded?

Comment: Here It's unclear, but I think you just have to compare the HTML version of each form. It will be clear. Perhaps the controller is not specified in the first version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails usually adds CSRF protection token in form of hidden fields into your HTML form, but only if you use the Rails helper methods. Compare this view

```
<% form_tag method: 'post', controller: 'checkout', action: 'place_order' do %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Place Order 2' %>
<% end %>
```

with this rendered output:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/checkout/place_order" method="post">
  <div style="display:none">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="q5PYT8i+XTlnoKeVqCoz8VMtKKSJP+CXQb/E+G0Vxlk=">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Place Order 2">
</form>
```

Now, to get your orginal form up and running, you can either insert this snippet into your `<form>` tag:

```
<%= hidden_field request_forgery_protection_token, value: form_authenticity_token %>
```

or you can disable CSRF protection **(not recommended at all!)**:

```
# in your app/controllers/application_controller.rb
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

You should at least read the [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) on why disabling the CSRF protection is a bad thing.

---

*N.B.* Is there a reason why you don't use [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-%23form_for+with+a+model+object)?

Answer (score 2):

I was going to write this as a comment, but it's too long

---

**Helpers**

As a rule, you generally need to use the Rails helpers (of which [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) is one) wherever possible.

The reason being that as Rails (& HTML) develops, you'll find that the helpers will adapt to keep up with current syntax, whereas using "naked" HTML will not. This not only keeps your application [conventional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), but [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

By manually typing out an HTML form, you not only open yourself up to syntax change issues, but also you won't get any of the benefits that Rails-integration provides, such as `CSRF` protection

---

**form_tag**

A quick note on your `form_tag`

You've defined the route for the `form_tag` by using `:controller` & `:action`. You'd be much better using one of the `route_helpers` that will be defined in your Rails `routes` file:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :checkout, path_names: { create: "place_order" }
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
<%= form_tag checkout_place_order_path do %>
```

It must also be noted that the `form_for` tag will actually employ the `:post` method by default

--

**Params**

You mention the `params` for your item are not being passed using your standard form.

The reason for this is actually quite simple - [Rails builds a `params` hash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) whenever you send data to the controller via an HTML form.

The issue you have is that if you define your form with "naked" HTML, those params will not be generated correctly (they are built from your form element names). This means if you want to send the correct data through to your application, you'll be much better suited to using one of the helpers, such as `form_for` (which is what you've now discovered)

---

**form_for**

As mentioned by `DMKE`, you *may* wish to use [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). This is different than `form_tag`, as it relies on having an `ActiveRecord` object to work with. You'd have to do it like this:

```
#app/controllers/checkout_controller.rb
Class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @checkout = Checkout.new
   end

   def create
       @checkout = Checkout.new(checkout_params)
       @checkout.save
   end
end
```

You can then populate a `form_for` with the following:

```
#app/views/checkout/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @checkout do |f| %>
```